# Assign aggregated value from one file to new variable in a different file

Tags: spss

I have an annual report, that covers results from 30 groups. I want to take the aggregated mean of values from last year from each group, and add it as a new variable to cases in the same group this year.

For example, if the mean value from last year for Group One was 91735, I want all cases in Group One this year to have a variable equal to 91735.

Answer (score 0):

AGGREGATE will produce the aggregated means in a dataset.  Then activate the other one and do a merge with MATCH FILES using the aggregated dataset as a table.  You can find all this on the Data menu.